# Session Authentication not working in Play when using Silhouette

Tags: playframework-2.6, silhouette

I am using `Silhouette` security library. My `Play` server seem to send empty `Session` information in response. What am I doing wrong?

Following is the print on `Play's` console just before sending response.

`Session(Map(authenticator -> 1-jtwBvA+LsLKE2rnkT/nMH1aQF9xc1twhECrma9mj3NUhUdVDmh/4wxQ2MxDOjcxkvEMTi1k63Dg5ezl+9FzDE3miaM5DbOrhyqAyGu4+30mHHV3QdPKA3IQQx5UdL1Hu85fZRI4f3Ef+q6xAgboDps0uBob5ojzo5Oqy8FNsoexn7Wr9iRyTr5xrMrLvl9GNQa+rA3q8qvW84sJaSei2iydrP2OjUbnnzo+zgrHLB3Bn7KJxOcFH4h9CikZNk/FHbtDm4uxzcK3paK1CuuIWLE8yvcYdavJ+4ejV5IaJ8QesJQRFgBktD9L/A2bc03eaA8wm)))`

But in the the browser window, I notice that the value is empty.

[image]

`Set-Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=; Max-Age=-86400;`

Note that my browser earlier already had a PLAY_SESSION cookie from previous test runs. However, I would expect that the client application (Angular) would override old cookies with new cookies. Am I correct?

Following is the code snippet which creates, initialised and embed session information

```
val AuthenticatorFuture: Future[SessionAuthenticator] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.create(loginInfo) //create authenticator

                      AuthenticatorFuture.flatMap(authenticator => { //got the authenticator
                        val securityTokenFuture: Future[Session] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.init(authenticator) //init authenticator
                        securityTokenFuture.flatMap(securityToken=> { 
                          println("adding security token: ",securityToken)
                          val result:Future[AuthenticatorResult] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.embed(securityToken, Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("found user"))))
                          result
```

The `Environment` is defined as

```
trait SessionEnv extends Env {
  type I = User 
  type A = SessionAuthenticator
}
```

As is passed to my controller as

```
silhouette: Silhouette[SessionEnv]
```

I created is at compile time as follows

```
val configSession =  SessionAuthenticatorSettings()
val sessionAuthenticatorService = new SessionAuthenticatorService(configSession,fingerprintGenerator,authenticatorEncoder,new DefaultSessionCookieBaker(),clock)
val sessionEnv = com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[SessionEnv](userIdentityService,sessionAuthenticatorService,Seq(),EventBus())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is probably expected behavior of `Play Framework` as `Silhouette` doesn't modify the session cookie. I noticed that the browser already had a previous expired cookie and it sends it in the `signin` request. When `Silhouette` authenticator sees the expired cookie, it sends an empty value back. I think this is to make the browser discard the previous cookie.

[image]